# How to get rid of a MemoryCache object in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC app where I am getting a XML file and loading into an object.

In my view I have several client/server operations and since MVC is stateless I stored the object into a MemoryCache (to prevent the constant loading of the XML file).  
While this seems to work nicely, however my concern is how to remove this MemoryChache item when I am done?

If the user goes to different view then I want to remove this object.

However I don't know what event I could use to ensure this object gets removed.

Comment: [MemoryCache.Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.remove(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I can handle it with JQuery:

```
$(window).unload(function () {
    // Server call to clear MemoryCache
});
```